# No Man’s Sky not updating to Endurance on Xbox One X

Tags: xbox-one, no-mans-sky

I’m so excited to play Endurance. That is, if I can download it. I’ve updated my console, uninstalled and reinstalled No Man’s Sky, restarted my console, and checked for updates, all to no avail.

Is there something I’m missing? Please help me!

Comment: I saw some users on Twitter saying they can't download the update either. You likely have to just wait. It's possible the update is slowly getting rolled out across regions.

Comment: That may be it. If anyone can find when that would be very helpful too (my patience is that of a Star Wars protagonist before becoming jedi)

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone in this predicament. There are many who are having issues downloading the Endurance update on the Xbox platform. Per Xbox/Microsoft Support, the Xbox release was delayed due to an issue on Hello Games side

> Just called Xbox Support, they said that the Endurance update is under “delayed release” and that the issue is coming from the developer.
>
> [Source](https://twitter.com/Archangel_5747/status/1550038619888537602?s=20&t=L3rcQLdMrcfycKfPdmy8NQ)

As Timmy Jim suggested, the best solution is to wait this out until the update is available for download. Late 07/21/2022, there were a few reports on Twitter stating the update finally came to their systems.